# Generate and open a link from input data

Tags: forms

I've a form where user can optionally enter their nickname, firstname and location. How can I generate a link from that data by submission and open it afterwards?

The link should look like this:

```
http://example.com/generated.php?nickname=hello&firstname=world&location=earth
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I get you right, but, using jQuery, you can do:

```
$('.my-form').serialize();
```

it will get the inputs and generate a get-like string.

Comment: Is it possible to do with pure JavaScript?